# What's the efficient way to swap two register variables in CUDA?

Tags: c++, cuda, swap

I'm starting to write some CUDA code, and I want to do the equivalent of `std::swap()` for two variables within a kernel; they're in the register file (no spillage, not in some buffer, etc.). Suppose I have the following device code:

```
__device__ foo(/* some args here */) {

    /* etc. */

    int x = /* value v1 */;
    int y = /* value v2 */;

    /* etc. */

    swap(x,y);

    /* etc. */
}
```

Now, I could just write

```
template <typename T> void swap ( T& a, T& b )
{
  T c(a); a=b; b=c;
}
```

but I wonder - isn't there some CUDA built-in for this functionality?

**Notes:**

- Yes, I want this to run for all threads.
- Never mind about whether I have enough registers or not. Assume that I have them.

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me. CUDA uses a Single Instruction Multiple Data (SIMD) processing scheme, which means that the instruction you are writing in a kernel function will be executed by all the threads in the computational grid. Depending on the grid size, you can have enough register space or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, this is all *completely irrelevant*.

`x` and `y` are not "real" objects: they only exist in the abstract machine described by the C++ standard. In particular, *they do not correspond to registers*.

You might imagine that the compiler when creating your program would assign them to registers, but that's *really* not how things work. The things being stored in registers can get shuffled around, duplicated, changed into something else, or even eliminated entirely.

In particular, unconditionally swapping two variables that are stored in registers usually *doesn't generate any code at all* — its only effect is for the compiler to adjust its internal tables of what objects are being stored in what registers at that point in time.

(even for a conditional swap, you're still usually better off letting the compiler do its thing)

Answer (score 7):

I have considered the following test program

```
template <typename T> __device__ void inline swap_test_device1(T& a, T& b)
{
    T c(a); a=b; b=c;
}

template <typename T> __device__ void inline swap_test_device2(T a, T b)
{
    T c(a); a=b; b=c;
}

__global__ void swap_test_global(const int* __restrict__ input1, const int* __restrict__ input2, int* output1, int* output2) {

    int tx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    int x = input1[tx]*input1[tx];
    int y = input2[tx]*input2[tx];

    //swap_test_device2(x,y);
    swap_test_device1(x,y);

    output1[tx] = x;
    output2[tx] = y;

}
```

and I have disassembled it. The result when using `swap_test_device1` and `swap_test_device2` is the same. The common disassembled code is the following

```
MOV R1, c[0x1][0x100];
S2R R0, SR_CTAID.X;
S2R R2, SR_TID.X;
MOV32I R9, 0x4;  
IMAD R3, R0, c[0x0][0x8], R2;
IMAD R6.CC, R3, R9, c[0x0][0x28];
IMAD.HI.X R7, R3, R9, c[0x0][0x2c];
IMAD R10.CC, R3, R9, c[0x0][0x20];
LD.E R2, [R6];                         loads input1[tx] and stores it in R2
IMAD.HI.X R11, R3, R9, c[0x0][0x24];
IMAD R4.CC, R3, R9, c[0x0][0x30];
LD.E R0, [R10];                        loads input2[tx] and stores it in R0
IMAD.HI.X R5, R3, R9, c[0x0][0x34];
IMAD R8.CC, R3, R9, c[0x0][0x38];
IMAD.HI.X R9, R3, R9, c[0x0][0x3c];
IMUL R2, R2, R2;                       R2 = R2 * R2
ST.E [R4], R2;                         stores input1[tx]*input1[tx] in global memory
IMUL R0, R0, R0;                       R0 = R0 * R0
ST.E [R8], R0;                         stores input2[tx]*input2[tx] in global memory
EXIT ;
```

It seems that the there is not an explicit swap in the disassembled code. In other words, the compiler, *for this simple example*, is capable to optimize the code directly writing `x` and `y` in the proper global memory locations.

**EDIT**

I have now considered the following more involved test case

```
__global__ void swap_test_global(const char* __restrict__ input1, const char* __restrict__ input2, char* output1, char* output2) {

    int tx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    char x = input1[tx];
    char y = input2[tx];

    //swap_test_device2(x,y);
    swap_test_device1(x,y);

    output1[tx] = (x >> 3) & y;
    output2[tx] = (y >> 5) & x;

 }
```

with the same above `__device__` functions. The disassembled code is

```
MOV R1, c[0x1][0x100];              
S2R R0, SR_CTAID.X;                 
S2R R2, SR_TID.X;           
IMAD R0, R0, c[0x0][0x8], R2;       R0 = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x
BFE R7, R0, 0x11f;
IADD R8.CC, R0, c[0x0][0x28];
IADD.X R9, R7, c[0x0][0x2c];
IADD R10.CC, R0, c[0x0][0x20];
LD.E.S8 R4, [R8];                   R4 = x = input1[tx]
IADD.X R11, R7, c[0x0][0x24];
IADD R2.CC, R0, c[0x0][0x30];
LD.E.S8 R5, [R10];                  R5 = y = input2[tx]
IADD.X R3, R7, c[0x0][0x34];
IADD R12.CC, R0, c[0x0][0x38];
IADD.X R13, R7, c[0x0][0x3c];
SHR.U32 R0, R4, 0x3;                R0 = x >> 3
SHR.U32 R6, R5, 0x5;                R6 = y >> 5
LOP.AND R5, R0, R5;                 R5 = (x >> 3) & y
LOP.AND R0, R6, R4;                 R0 = (y >> 5) & x
ST.E.U8 [R2], R5;                   global memory store
ST.E.U8 [R12], R0;                  global memory store
EXIT ;
```

As it can be seen, there is still no apparent register swap.

Comment: In your example, the compiler is able to avoid doing a swap. If you make it a bit more contrived - say, take the result of the swap and reverse its bits, or take its upper 3/4 of the bits modulo the lower 1/4 of the bits - the compiler would not be able to do this.

Comment: @einpoklum In my answer above, I have underlined that it is a _simple_ example. At this moment, I cannot imagine what (in principle, of course) can prevent the compiler to avoid swapping the registers, even if I make operations after the swap. Anyway, I will try.

Comment: I understand, but that doesn't answer my question of whether there's some builtin CUDA function or PTX instruction for swapping.

Comment: @einpoklum I have added another, more involved, test-case and it seems that still no register swap occurs. I'm not aware of any CUDA function performing register swap but, following the above results, I start wondering whether such a function would be needed or not. In principle, nothing would prevent the compiler to just interchange register names to perform a swap. As you know, registers are per-thread. If you are interested in swapping registers belonging to different threads (but this is different from what you are currently asking), then shuffle operations could be of your interest.

Comment: @einpoklum I'm not sure your edit is correct. The templated functions seem to be skipped by the compiler.

Comment: By the way, you realize your second function can't have any effect - any compiler would just cancel it out, since it only modifies its local variables.

Comment: If the swap is conditional, will this still hold? Unfortunately, I don't think so...?